# Fully clearing a Clipping Border

Tags: python, 3d-view

I've written some code that creates a clipping region using **bpy.ops.view3d.clip_border(..)** then to clear the clipping region I call **bpy.ops.view3d.clip_border()** again (with no values). This clears the region after a viewport re-draw, however, running **context.space_data.region_3d.use_clip_planes()** will return True and the viewport will still display "Clipped" in brackets in the info text.

Is there a way to completely clear the clipping through code, just like pressing Alt+B would do?

[image: Clipping Border]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use_clip_planes` is not readonly, you can change its value.

You can disable the label with
`context.space_data.region_3d.use_clip_planes = False`.

It won't update in the viewport until your mouse enters the 2D space or you manually call a redraw : `context.space_data.region_3d.tag_redraw()`

[Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It fixed the issue. I can now set context.space_data.region_3d.use_clip_planes each time I clear the clipping region. I hadn't thought to check if it could be set. Cheers